# Cassandra Materialized view

Tags: cassandra

Assume this schema

```
CREATE TABLE t(
        a int,
        b int,
        c int,
        d int,
        e text,
        f date,
        g int,
        PRIMARY KEY (a,b)
)
```

I we create following mv

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW t_mv as
        select a,b,c,d from t where c is not null and d is not null
         PRIMARY KEY (c,d,a,b);
```

What happens if we run this query

```
UPDATE t SET g=1 WHERE a=10 AND b = 20
```

As you can see "g" is excluded in "t_mv" , I want to know what cassandra doing internaly?

Is there any overhead for t_mv , or cassandra smartly detect there is no changes for t_mv and no-operation

for example If we have 10 materialized view like above-mentioned , is Update that excluded in mv impact performance? or the performance in equal to when there is no mv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra does not send mutation to materialized view in above condition.

Did a quick demo on local system with your table structure and below is TRACE output.[image]

While updating columns which is present in Materialized view gives below TRACE:
[image]

I hope this answers your question.